# citation works fine in Texworks but not in texniccenter

Tags: miktex, natbib, texniccenter

Citation doesn't work using texniccenter and I received warning of: package natbib warning there were undefined citations and (???) instead of reference

i am using TexnicCenter V 2.02 and Miktex 2.9.
[image]

However, the code works just fine using Texworks and references are shown properly.

For the following code:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\journal{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{}
\author{}
\address{}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
Test Test \cite{test}.
\section*{References}
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} 
  \bibliography{TankerModel}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: the editor you use to write the file makes no difference to the errors from tex. Have you run latex multiple times to resolve the cross references? warnings about undefined references are expected on the first run. you then need to run bibtex and then run latex at least two more times

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I built the tex file and bibtex file many times but nothing happen. I always receive these warning

Comment: If you run `bibtex` by hand, does it work? Best guess without logs is that `bibtex` is not being run.

Comment: @cfr  How to run it by hand please?

Comment: From a menu would probably do. Or on the command line `bibtex <name of file without extension>`.